# How to export data frame in Jupyter as a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter

I have a data frame saved as `df` in a jupyter notebook, and i want to export it into a csv file on my desktop.

Comment: you can use -->df.to_csv("location"+"file_name.csv") command. for example:
df.to_csv("C:/Users/Mycsvfile.csv")

Answer (score 5):

For a pandas data frame you can use `df.to_csv('data.csv')`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: where is the data.csv files stored?

Comment: it is relative to where you run your code, in this case in the same directory as your notebook

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in pandas `DataFrame` then you can use `.to_csv()` function from pandas to export your data in CSV .

Here's how you can save data in desktop

```
df.to_csv("<path to desktop and filename>")

# If you just use file name then it will save CSV file in working directory.
# Example path : C:/Users/<>/Desktop/<file name>.csv
```

If you want to learn more about it you can visit [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).