# Can Jupyter labs or pandas serve static files?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

If I am running a [Jupyter notebook server](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#running-a-notebook-server) where an analyst can browse into server URL to run IPython, (typical IPython but hosted remotely) can the analyst export the data in CSV form as well to their local machine? Like download CSV file they are working on from a Pandas data wrangling process?

For example if a Pandas data frame is created something like this method below of IPython hosted remotely from an SQL query:

```
# Example python program to read data from a PostgreSQL table
# and load into a pandas DataFrame
import psycopg2
import pandas as pds
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create an engine instance
alchemyEngine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://test:@127.0.0.1', pool_recycle=3600);

# Connect to PostgreSQL server
dbConnection = alchemyEngine.connect();

# Read data from PostgreSQL database table and load into a DataFrame instance
dataFrame = pds.read_sql("select * from \"StudentScores\"", dbConnection);

pds.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False);

# Print the DataFrame
print(dataFrame);

# Close the database connection
dbConnection.close();
```

Would Jupyter labs have something to similar of serving a static file like a web server can do? For example a Flask server you can serve static file, sorry NOT a web developer but I have experimented with this in with Flask. The Flask code looks like this below for `send_file` to serve a static file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
import io
import os
import csv 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/get_csv')
def get_csv():
    """ 
    Returns the monthly weather csv file (Montreal, year=2019)
    corresponding to the month passed as parameter.
    """
    # Checking that the month parameter has been supplied
    if not "month" in request.args:
        return "ERROR: value for 'month' is missing"
    # Also make sure that the value provided is numeric
    try:
        month = int(request.args["month"])
    except:
        return "ERROR: value for 'month' should be between 1 and 12"
    csv_dir  = "./static"
    csv_file = "2019_%02d_weather.csv" % month
    csv_path = os.path.join(csv_dir, csv_file)
    
    # Also make sure the requested csv file does exist
    if not os.path.isfile(csv_path):
        return "ERROR: file %s was not found on the server" % csv_file
    # Send the file back to the client
    return send_file(csv_path, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=csv_file)
```

Can a IPython or pandas serve a static file if IPython is hosted on a remote machine?

Comment: Can't the user do `dataFrame.to_csv("<path to desktop and filename>")`?  Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645918/how-to-export-data-frame-in-jupyter-as-a-csv-file?

Comment: That works if your running jupyter labs locally to save a file to a directory on the same machine its running on. I was hoping to research if this could be done to an external machine, or even like a network/share point drive?

Comment: If I'm understnading things corectly, I think what you mean to ask are in the first paragraph and last line? (I'm guess all that stuff in between was from you looking for a solution.) You'd build in what ditkin is showing you to do and then you use [the Jupyter Dashboard](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ui_components.html#notebook-dashboard) to download the generated `.csv` file to your local machine that is connected to the server.

Comment: I'm confused if you are using JupyterLab or the Jupyter Notebook? What you linked to was the Jupyter notebook interface. If you are using JupyterLab, you can still download from the local machine to your local system. It's just the file navigation panel should be obvious on the left side, or you can switch to it and download there.

Comment: I think Jupyter labs and Jupyter notebook. I run Jupyter labs to bring up a Jupyter notebook

Comment: So Jupyter notebook is a way to connect to a data base, do some data wrangling, and then hoping to export the CSV data to a local machine. (Jupyter labs hosted remotely)

Comment: So you know, the interface you linked to isn't JupyterLab? Look at the User interface [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ui_components.html). That isn't JupyterLab. But anyway, what I spelled out holds. Connected to JupyterLab in your browser, you can look at the CSV nicely there because JupyterLab has a built in viewer. You can download that CSV file from the file navigation pane by right-clicking and selecting download.

Comment: Oh ok I wasnt aware Jupyter notebook wasnt part of Jupyter labs.

Comment: So you are actually running a JupyterLab server. I usually try to spell it out as 'classic Jupyter notebook interface' vs. 'JupyterLab' just for the reason the notebook part in the name can get confusing The are different interfaces that both serve Jupyter notebooks as one of the main files. Right now the interfaces are quite different in underlying parts with JupyterLab being much more modern. Soon the underlying machinery for the classic interface is going to get an overhaul to be more like JupyterLab. So using  the term 'classic' interface might get a little more confusing.

Comment: if you are actually running a jupyterlab server on a remote machine, you can download a file to the remote machine (using ipython, notebook, etc) and then open the file using the jupyterlab browser. have you tried doing this? this is a very straightforward operation - it would be helpful to know what you've tried and where you're stuck. as your question is now, the answer is just "yes"

Comment: see https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/file_formats.html#delimiter-separated-values